# Magento 1.7 language switcher on category page removes store code from URL

Tags: magento-1.7

I have read a lot about the issue on stack but could not find a similar issue.
On magento 1.7

The language switcher on a my category pages removes store code from URL's. 
     site.com/store/pt/vestidos
     --> site.com/store/dresses 
 while it should be site.com/store/en/dresses

Strangely enough, this does not happen with products
     site.com/store/pt/product_in_portuguese.html 
     --> site.com/store/en/product_in_english.html

Another maybe related issue is that on my store home I also get an error upon language switch
     www.site.com/store 
     --> which through .htaccess redirects to www.site.com/store/pt
when I use the language switch there 
     --> site.com/store/en/?___from_store=pt gives me
  "There was no Home CMS page configured or found"
while going to site.com/store/en/home works just fine.

My configuration
Add storecode to URL's - Yes
mod-rewrite enabled

Comment: I still have the same issue. Does anyone have an Idea how I could solve this? Thanks